# React component loading below the the current Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component `Navbar` which in navigation Menu.  When I click Login the `UserForm` components open up. And UserForm component has another Routing for a creating-account page with component `UserRegister`.

So, now the problem is when I click on the `<Link>` on `userForm` page it calls the component `UserRegister`  but prints it Ui just below the current component Ui (`UserForm`) and changes the Url perfectly.

SO the thing is Navbar -> Login -> UserForm (This component prints just below the current component).

I want to open it on a new refreshed Page. I tried working it out with withRouter and other different sources but I just can not see one mistake that is causing it to load below.

I have removed access of JSX.

Navbar.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

//components
import MainPage from "./MainPage";
export default function TopNavbar() {
  return (
    
        <Nav className="ml-auto">
          <Link to="/" className="Link">
            <p className="link-text"> Home</p>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/Login" className="Link">
            <p className="link-text"> Login User</p>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/" className="Link">
            <img src={img} className="avatar-img" alt="avatar" />
          </Link>
            </Navbar>
  );
}
```

UserForm.js

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

//components
import UserRegister from "./UserRegister";

export default function UserForm() {
  return (
    <Router>
      
            <form method="post">
              <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" className="error" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" className="error" />
 <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary login-button" />
            </form>

            <div className="further-links">
              <Link to="/forgot-password">
                <p>Forgot Password</p> <br />
              </Link>
              <Link to="/create-account">
                <p>Create New Account </p>
              </Link>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/forgot-password" component={""} />
                <Route exact path="/create-account" component={UserRegister} />
              </Switch>

              <br />
            </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[sandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/findstudybuddy-1qwpo?file=/src/components/UserForm.js:0-1425)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with codesandbox, seems like it has some problems with updating accordingly.

But if you move your route from the Userform, to App.js instead. What does that give you?

Comment: Do you see my forked site here?: https://codesandbox.io/s/findstudybuddy-forked-0mkev

Comment: Yes, I can see that. It is running in my browser.

Comment: When I move my route in app.js , then only URL changes but Ui does not update.

Comment: Wel Tahnkyou for your help. Can you please explain why this error was occurring. For better Understanding.

Comment: Yep. So I've changed a few things. 
Firste I moved the router stuff to App.js, in that way you have everything in the same file. Next I change the import, to only import "Link" from "react-router-dom" 

Then in App.js, I cleaned the import as well.
Then cleaned the Route, removed exact from the routes, you only need that in the route to your MainPage component.
Then in index.js I cleaned the import, and change a few things in the ReactDom.render, where I also added 'strict mode'.